# The book of Al-Bidayah wan nihayah By Ibn Kathir?

Tags: history, uloom-al-hadith, authenticity, books

Salaam Alaikum

The book of Al-Bidayah wan nihayah "The beginning and the end" is this book authentic does it have weak narrations?

Answer (score 1):

In the most of his book, Ibn Kathir **followed the approach of Hadith** , he observed the narration substantiation and criticism, **explained the Hadith degree** without invalidating the bond to judge the Hadiths and narrations, as per the approach of scholars of his time, he put a great effort to accomplish that.

Although he relied mainly on the integrity of the bond in Hadith and news, **but he allowed some weak narrations** and flimsy news , especially in the news of past, incidents of **pre-Islam**, elves stories, news of prophecy signs and some other news that contradicts with logic and has no historical value, scientific basis or religious consideration in "Shariaa".

In fact Ibn Kathir gives the feeling in many of the cases that he narrated some historians’ ravings and myths, but reported them to follow former historians to respond to them or to point them out.. He asked excuse in such cases, as saying:

> were it not for it was reported in many interpretation and history
>   books, we would not mention it with its weakness and contradiction
>   with the reasonable and the narrated.

.